# Is there any easier way to add multiple users to a library?

Tags: libraries

I have to add around 1000 users to few of my libraries. I tried using data loader but i am not able to find related table. Is this table exposed by salesforce?

Is there any easy way to add users to a library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach

1. Create a public group(s) that is subscribed to the library
2. Use Dataloader to assign the users to the public group(s) by inserting into SObject `GroupMember`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

1. Create a public group.
2. Add members to the public group through data loader. Use GroupMember Object to insert multiple users in a public group.
3. Add the public group to the libraries.